# How to embed powerbi report without iframe in website using any javascript library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-js-api

I am trying to integrate powerbi report in my website. But the **powerbi-client** node module servers the report output in iframe. My requirement is to load the powerbi report in a website page without iframe so that our report will not be served from third party website.

Is there anyway we can achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the embedded Power BI content **always** will be server from Power BI infrastructure! If you **must** do this in your network, then you should install [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/), which is an on-premise version of Power BI (or use another reporting solution, e.g. [SSRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports?view=sql-server-2017)). Licensing Power BI Report Server requires Power BI Premium P SKU or SQL Server Enterprise with software assurance.

Comment: how about PowerBI Embedded?

Comment: Power BI Embedded is service running in Azure to run reports in dedicated capacity instead of the shared one. But you still need to publish to Power BI Service. The difference is only that you can assign a dedicated capacity to the workspace where your report is published and get better performance or get rid of some noisy neighbours

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Embedded always run inside an iframe.
Why do you need to embed a report without an iframe?

Comment: that was a requirement